# Why dart analyzer fails to recognize a type error?

Tags: dart

Here's the code:

```dart
static const _defaults = <String, dynamic>{
  'api_key': '4839234792374',
  'enabled': false,
  'concurrency': 4,
};

String getString(String key) {
  return _remoteConfig == null ?
    _defaults.containsKey(key) && _defaults[key] :
    _remoteConfig.getString(key);
}
```

The bug is obvious (and shame on me, was produced by blind copy-paste from similar `getBool(key)` function. If the `_remoteConfig` is `null`, the execution hits the `bool && String` path and I get the runtime exception `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'`. Totally legit, but why does analyzer not see it? The execution flow is crystal clear, one path returns `String` another path (theoretically) returns `dynamic` and the return type is `String` which means that all paths return `String`.
What I don't understand?

Dart 2.12.0
pedantic 1.11.0

Analyzer options:

```yaml
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml

analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/generated/*
    - lib/**/*.g.dar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking two questions:

1. Why doesn't the analyzer complain about `_defaults.containsKey(key) && _defaults[key]`?
2. Why doesn't the analyzer complain about the ternary expression with different types along its two paths?

For #1: Since `_defaults[key]` returns type `dynamic` (which could be a `bool` at runtime), I wouldn't expect an analysis complaint.

For #2: Since the two paths have different types, **the type of the ternary expression is the common base type**: `Object`.  If implicit casts are enabled, `Object` is then automatically cast to the `String` return type.

The analyzer *does* catch both errors if you [disable implicit casts](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks) in your `analysis_options.yaml` configuration file:

```yaml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```

Running the analyzer then prints:

> error • The operands of the operator '&&' must be assignable to 'bool' at ... • (non_bool_operand)

> error • A value of type 'Object' can't be returned from the function 'getString' because it has a return type of 'String' at ... • (return_of_invalid_type)

(I'm surprised that `implicit-casts: false` triggers an analysis error for the `&&` expression with a `dynamic` operand,; maybe my understanding isn't quite accurate, or maybe that's a bug in the analyzer.)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, more correct version of your answer would be "Dude, check that you **actually** use 2.12". My `pubspec.yaml` was still `sdk: ">=2.9.0 <3.0.0"`, the correct line would be `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`  As of 2.12 implicit downcasts are gone (https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety ): "So with null safety we are removing implicit downcasts entirely." Proof: ```Object x = 42; 
int i = x; 
print(i);``` in DartPad with null safety bombs out.

Comment: Ah, yes.  The stricter type checking from Dart 2.12 will catch #2 without needing to set `implicit-casts: false`. (It won't generate an error for #1 however, although that's arguably desirable.)